# Validating generated strings quickly (+ maths)

Tags: python

I'm trying to validate a large amount of generated strings, pumped out by itertools.permutations

The way I'd like to validate them is checking if every overlapping 2 characters are found in an array I have set up, the string is only valid if every overlapping 2 strings are in the "paths" array

I have the following code to validate:

```
def valid(s):
    matches = re.findall("(?=(..))", s)
    for match in matches:
       if match not in paths:
           return False
    return True
```

Now I'm wondering if this can get any faster since it's too slow for my liking, I assume a non regex solution would be faster

Also I was wondering if it was possible to pre-calculate how many accepted strings I will have, given that: every character in the paths array is in the itertools iterable* (so keyspace is known) and the size of the "paths" array is also known

Edit: Paths currently has 250 combinations

This is the iterable "1920eran876i3om54lstchdkgbvupywjfx"

example valid output:

```
1920876
1920873
1920875
1920874
1920867
1920863
1920865
1920864
1920834
1920857
```

Comment: Could you provide an example? What does `paths` look like? What do your strings look like? Which of those strings are valid?

Comment: Also, is there are reason you're not **only** generating string that **are** valid?

Comment: One could probably generate all strings consisting of only character pairs found in your string array.  That may generate *more* things than you are currently getting, since it is not clear what you are generating permutations of, or what you are checking it against.  Can you give some example input and expected output?

Comment: @Scott you mean 4 for loops in my case? I guess that would work as well and be a lot faster, and then I also know how many valid ones I will get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this by realising that your regex simply matches every two-character pair. You can get this by zipping two different iterators, like so:

```
def valid(s):
    for c, d in zip(s[:-1], s[1:]):
       if c + d not in paths:
           return False
    return True
```

It *might* be faster to iterate through indices and use slice on every loop, but you'd have to test it.

I've been assuming that `paths` is a string, but if it's a `Sequence[str]` you can make it a `set` for extra performance.

You can speed this up further by hand-coding Python byte code, but that's probably a bit excessive.

Comment: Well, the `set` part is knocking O(n) down to O(1) for each loop, and regular expressions are sometimes quite slow... But not really.

Answer (score 0):

If `paths` is a list `[]` it would make things quicker to turn it into a set `set()` or `{items}` as a set uses a hashtable and therefore you don't have to check through the whole list if the item you're looking for is at the end.